# Creation of std::thread slows down main program by 50%

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

merely creating a thread and joining it slows down execution of the main thread by 50%. As you can see in the example below the thread does nothing and still has a significant effect on performance. I thought it might be a power/frequency scaling related issue, so I tried to sleep after creating the thread to no avail. The program below if compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o out thread_test.cpp -pthread
```

shows the result of

```
Before thread() trial 0 time: 312024526 ignore -1593025974
Before thread() trial 1 time: 243018707 ignore -494037597
Before thread() trial 2 time: 242929293 ignore 177714863
Before thread() trial 3 time: 242935290 ignore 129069571
Before thread() trial 4 time: 243113945 ignore 840242475
Before thread() trial 5 time: 242824224 ignore -1635749271
Before thread() trial 6 time: 242809490 ignore -1256215542
Before thread() trial 7 time: 242910180 ignore -555222712
Before thread() trial 8 time: 235645414 ignore 537501443
Before thread() trial 9 time: 235746347 ignore 118363977
After thread() trial 0 time: 567509646 ignore 223146324
After thread() trial 1 time: 476450035 ignore -393907838
After thread() trial 2 time: 476377789 ignore -1678874628
After thread() trial 3 time: 476377012 ignore -1015350122
After thread() trial 4 time: 476185152 ignore 2034280344
After thread() trial 5 time: 476420949 ignore -1647334529
After thread() trial 6 time: 476354679 ignore 441573900
After thread() trial 7 time: 476120322 ignore -1576726357
After thread() trial 8 time: 476464850 ignore -895798632
After thread() trial 9 time: 475996533 ignore -997590921
```

whereas all trials should be the same speed.

EDIT: use rdtsc() for time measurement, use larger duration, use computed result

thread_test.cpp:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int dorands(){
  int a =0;
  for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){
   a +=rand();
  }
  return a;
}

inline uint64_t rdtsc(){
  uint32_t lo, hi;
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "xorl %%eax, %%eax\n"
    "cpuid\n"
    "rdtscp\n"
    : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi)
    :
    : "%ebx", "%ecx" );
  return (uint64_t)hi << 32 | lo;
}


int foo(){return 0;}

int main(){

  uint64_t begin;
  uint64_t end;

  for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    begin= rdtsc();
    volatile int e = dorands();
    end = rdtsc();
    std::cout << "Before thread() trial "<<i<<" time: " << end-begin << " ignore " << e << std::endl;;
  }

  std::thread t1(foo);
  t1.join();

  for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    begin= rdtsc();
    volatile int e = dorands();
    end = rdtsc();
    std::cout << "After thread() trial "<<i<<" time: " << end-begin << " ignore " << e << std::endl;;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Clang reproduces, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0053133d6b4b63fd, but this GCC is being wierd: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f8bd872a974529f.  Not sure why all the downvotes

Comment: Don't use `clock()` for profilling

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-O2`?

Comment: Is this possible that `rand()` has inconsistent run times on different calls?

Comment: Visual studio http://rextester.com/ZZEDT30189 doesn't appear to reproduce either.

Comment: [Better results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d96a4fd91cddd21) using `<chrono>`

Comment: @Drop: Results appear pretty consistent: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/992e6cc9e114efb4

Comment: @T.C.: Why?  The results here are pretty clear, chrono should offer no additional accuracy nor insight.

Comment: @MooingDuck When the apparent unit from `clock()` is 10000? I'd claim that chrono's facilities offers much better accuracy.

Comment: @MooingDuck /OT Hey, cool online VS compiler. Good to know that!

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't see how `10000` and `20000` can be consistent (not even mentioning that those are suspiciously well-rounded numbers)

Comment: @Drop http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38d5bf0af4672649

Comment: Perhaps the added thread is triggering new scheduling priorities by the OS?  Try monitoring the number of context switches with pidstat under various scenarios.

Comment: @T.C.: I didn't say the _numbers_ were accurate, I said the _results were consistent and clear_.  More accuracy doesn't change that.

Comment: I suspect that has to do with the state that `rand()` needs to manage for the PRNG (thread-local state?). Using a single `mt19937` doesn't show the same issue.

Comment: This probably has something with available hardware concurrency, I get different results on machines with different number of cores and same OS/gcc versions. MSVC results are completely crazy as both `clock()` and `chrono` are broken

Comment: `boost::chrono` + `boost::thread` (1.57) give expected results for me on MSVC-2013 and GCC 4.9.2, so we can say that it's limited to libstdc++

Comment: @Drop [Reproduced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54ee8ff20888d385) with libc++.

Comment: Using g++ 4.8.2, replacing rand() by rand_r(&seed), where seed is a a single global variable, gives an opposite result

Comment: addressed some of your concerns, tried -O2 and many different iteration counts, results are consistent

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::rand()` is C `rand()` which, under glibc, [invokes `__random()`](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.21/rand_8c_source.html#l00025). `__random()` [invokes `__libc_lock_lock()` and `__libc_lock_unlock()`](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.21/random_8c_source.html#l00292), and I don't think it's a stretch to imagine that if we delve deeper into that code, we'll find that the locks are essentially a no-op until a thread is created.

Comment: I wanted to get a _proof_, but glibc is such a mess of macros and conditions that I reached my SO answer time-and-effort threshold. :)

Comment: annotating the source code via perf revealed that after creating the thread time is spend in: lock   cmpxchg %esi,0x384b74(%rip)

Comment: tl;dr rand() is optimized for single threaded operation, once more thread spawns then it slows down a bit, instead use a thread local/local state random generator seeded with rand() (or better).

Answer (score 10):

I think you're running into a basic problem: at least on a typical multitasking operating system, there's a range from around (say) a few millseconds up to a second or so within which it's difficult to get meaningful timing measurements.

For extremely short sequences, you can use a clock-counter (e.g., RDTSC on x86), and run it a few times. If a task switch happens during the run, it'll stick out *really* badly, as a run that takes many times longer than the rest.

That points to the real problem: as soon as you get to a sequence (such as yours) that takes long enough that it's almost certain that at least one task switch *will* happen while it's running, then you run into a problem: the time lost to task switching can throw the timing off significantly. In particular, if a task switch happens during one run, but not during another, it can make the second appear significantly faster than the first.

Eventually, you get to tasks that take long enough that all of them include several task switches, so the difference due to the number of task switches gets pretty much lost in the noise.

Note: in theory, `clock` is supposed to measure only CPU time, not wall-clock time. In reality, it's nearly impossible to completely factor out all task switching time.

Your test demonstrates (or may demonstrate, anyway) another fairly basic problem: your `dorand()` computes something, but doesn't (for example) print out the result. A sufficiently intelligent compiler may (easily) be able to deduce that it has essentially no effect, and basically factor it out completely.

Even if you print out the results from `dorand`, you haven't seeded the random number generator, so it's required to produce identical results on each run. Again, a sufficiently intelligent compiler could figure that out, and compute the proper result at compile time, and just print out the three correct results. To prevent that we could (as one possibility) seed the random number differently on each run--the usual way is to retrieve the current time, and pass that to `srand`.

To eliminate (or at least reduce) those problems, we could rewrite the code something like this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

long long int dorands(){
  long long int a =0;
  for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++){
    a +=rand();
  }
  return a;
}

int foo(){return 0;}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
  clock_t begin = clock();
  long long int e = dorands();
  clock_t end = clock();
  std::cout << "ignore: " << e << ", trial 1 time: " << end-begin << std::endl;;

  begin = clock();
  e = dorands();
  end = clock();
  std::cout << "ignore: " << e << ", trial 2 time: " << end - begin << std::endl;;

  std::thread t1(foo);
  t1.join();

  begin = clock();
  e = dorands();
  end = clock();
  std::cout << "ignore: " << e << ", trial 3 time: " << end - begin << std::endl;;

  begin = clock();
  e = dorands();
  end = clock();
  std::cout << "ignore: " << e << ", trial 4 time: " << end - begin << std::endl;;


  return 1;
}
```

Here I've printed out the value returned from `dorand`, so the compiler can't just skip doing the calls to `rand` completely. I've also increased the number inside `dorand` so each trial runs for at least a second (on my computer, they do anyway).

Running it, I get results like this:

```
ignore: 1638407535924, trial 1 time: 1519
ignore: 1638386748597, trial 2 time: 1455
ignore: 1638433228933, trial 3 time: 1433
ignore: 1638288863328, trial 4 time: 1491
```

In this particular run, the first trials are slower (on average) than the second trials, but there's enough variation and overlap that we're probably pretty safe guessing that it's just noise--if there's any real difference in average speed, it's much too small for us to measure.

Comment: Strangely enough, if `rand()` is replaced by a PRNG with *local* state, such as `std::minstd_rand`, I cannot reproduce the issue, even though the timings are in the same ballpark as `rand()`'s. (I wonder if the lock that is used in glibc's implementation of `rand()` has something to do with it.)

Comment: @dyp: It's hard to guess--I'm not sure there's anything there to start with. When I first downloaded and ran his code, I got results that matched his pretty closely. Then I ran it again, and got almost precisely the opposite. I'm not entirely convinced what he's seeing is any more than noise.

Comment: Not sure on what machine you ran your code, but on a Linux Xeon E3-1231 I get higher numbers (ignore), much higher times, and results that are consistent with the OP.

Comment: I have edited my code above to address your concerns and I still have consistent unexplainable results.

Comment: and btw: I used volatile e in my first version already to avoid g++ optimizing out the call to rand